# Proccess.WaitForExit() throws Thread was being aborted?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Thread was being aborted error when using process.waitforexit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028241/thread-was-being-aborted-error-when-using-process-waitforexit)

Here's the stack trace

```
Message :Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(SafeWaitHandle waitHandle, UInt32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int64 timeout, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.WaitForExit(Int32 milliseconds)
```

Code is as follows:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public Double executeAsJob()
    {
            myThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(runThread));
            myThread.Start();
            return RUNNING;
    }

    public void runThread() {
            try {
                System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = ...;
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = ...;
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit(); // <-- THIS line throws the exception

                // Save exit code 
                iResult = proc.ExitCode;
            } catch (Exception e) { ... } 
    }
```

... Any ideas on this?

Comment: +1 I have never seen firing up application by Process in a WebMethod